# Sending 'GET' data with $.load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

Here is my function:

```
function loadNext(choice) {
    $("#thequestion").load("question.php", { ans: choice, id: "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>", nextId: "<?php echo $nextQuestionId; ?>" } );

    $("#graph").load("graph.php", { id:"<?php echo $row['id']; ?>", nextId: "<?php echo $nextQuestionId; ?>" } );
}
```

I execute the function and Firebug says the data is being posted, eg:

```
 Parameters:
    ans y
    id  3
    nextId  1
 Source:
    ans=y&id=3&nextId=1
```

But when I try to retrieve them in 'question.php' or 'graph.php' like so:

```
$id=$_GET["id"];
$nextId=$_GET["nextId"];
```

They echo back as null.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've just noticed that the webiste URL does not change when the function is executed. Shouldn't `ans=y&id=3&nextId=1` be appended onto it for the data to be sent? Or is this not the case for jQuery/ajax stuff?

EDIT 2: Sorry, this may be becoming really specific, but if I append the 
`/question.php?ans=y&id=3&nextId=1`
manually, it all works fine! So now I'm really confused - this has narrowed the problem down to the function loadNext(choice), has it not?

Edit - (not op) suggested edit to include javascript and jquery tags.

Comment: The website URL will not change. The AJAX request happens in the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery `load()` API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Either change your PHP script to look in `$_POST` (or `$_REQUEST` if you're feeling lazy) or change the JavaScript to

```
$.get("question.php", {
    ans: choice,
    id: "<?php echo $row['id'] ?>",
    nextId: "<?php echo $nextQuestionId ?>"
}, function(data) {
    $("#thequestion").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Phil, you are my hero. Thankyou so much. I've been trying to get this for so long you wouldn't believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well,

```
function loadNext(choice) {
        $("#thequestion").load("question.php?ans=choice&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&nextId=<?php echo $nextQuestionId; ?>" } );

        $("#graph").load("graph.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&nextId=<?php echo $nextQuestionId; ?>" } );
    }
```